# What is the most efficient way of adding additional functionaliy for admin only

Tags: plugins, themes, admin, functions, options

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to add additional functionality that will only be utilized by admins via /wp-admin.

What's the best way to implement so that resources aren't being wasted. I.E. if statement each page load or any other code execution on each page load for areas not even pertaining to the dashboard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is number of [dynamic hooks in admin-header.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L59) that allows to precisely target on which pages to load your code.

And naturally [`current_user_can()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) check so it only runs for admins.